# limit of products of zero and infinity

Tags: limits

Suppose F is a CDF of a discrete random variable where the random variable can take 1, 2 to infinity.
so $$\lim_{n \to \infty}F(n) = 1$$

I'd like to prove

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(nF(n)-n) = 0$$

I don't think I can apply product of two limits or addition of two limits, can I?

I was trying to prove

$E[X]=\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{k=0}^n (1-F(k)))$

I derived $E[X] = \lim_{n \to \infty}( n(F(n)-1) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-F(k)) )$
by the following

$E[X] = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=0}^n (k*P(k))) = \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} (   \\
  1*(F(1) - F(0))   \\
+ 2*(F(2) - F(1))   \\
+ ..  \\
+ n*(F(n) - F(n-1)))  \\
=    \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} (   \\
1 - F(0) +  \\
1 - F(1) +  \\
+ ..   \\
1 - F(n-1) +  \\
+ n*F(n) -n) \\ 
= \lim_{n \to \infty}( n(F(n)-1) + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-F(k)) )$

If my derivation is not flawed, then the limit should be 0, (if the statement (E(X) = the sum) I'm trying to prove is correct),
otherwise my derivation is flawed..
(Or this very statement is flawed..)

Comment: If you're just saying $F$ is a CDF of a random variable supported on the positive integers, then this isn't true.  If you're not saying that, I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: Writing it as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F(n)-1}{1/n}$ makes it easier to see that it's not necessarily 0. We don't have any guarantee about the rate at which the numerator approaches 0.

Comment: @Karl thanks, where did my derivation fail then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fasle. For example, if $X$ takes the values $1,2,...$ with $P(X=j)=\frac c {j^{2}}$ ($c$ chosen such that these probabilites add up to $1$) then $n(F(n)-1) \to -1$.

EDIT: If $EX<\infty$ then $n(1-F(n))$ does tend to $0$. Indeed, $n(1-F(n))\leq EX1_{X>n} \to 0$ by DCT.

Argument avoiding DCT: $EX1_{X>n}= \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} kP(X=k)$ and $EX=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} kP(X=k)<\infty$.  If you have a convergent series $\sum a_n$ of non-negative numbers then   $\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} kP(X=k) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: sorry can you take another look at op? did you mean $n(F(n)-1) \to -1$ ?

Comment: @eugene Yes, there was  a typo.

Comment: umm, sad i can't see how I can get -1 , but can you take a look at why my reasoning failed in edited OP?

Comment: @eugene If $EX<\infty$ then your conclusion golds. I have edited my answer.

Comment: is DCT https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem ? just wanna confirm if the reasoning behind the proof is beyond my reach at this moment

Comment: @eugene I have added a proof which does not use DCT.